# Foreach $_session[array] then using the result as a switch - case value

Tags: php, session, foreach, switch-statement, case

I have this code

```
<?php 
        session_start();

switch($sb) {

   foreach ($_SESSION['myarray'] as $result){

     case $result:
 echo "id"$result;
 break;
   }
 }
?>
```

This is giving me the following error and I can't work out why:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH, expecting T_CASE or T_DEFAULT or '}' on the foreach line.

Whilst this works:

```
<?php

    foreach ($_SESSION['myarray'] as $result){
         echo "SB: ".$result.",<br>";
    }


 ?>
```

and outputs as:

SB id: 1,
SB id: 2,
SB id: 3,
SB id: 4,
SB id: 10,
SB id: 11,
SB id: 12,
SB id: 13,

Can anyone see what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot have `foreach` like that inside a switch. It expects one or more `case`. Check the manual http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Suggest you look up the structure of a switch statement in the PHP docs

Comment: I think you need to be more clear with what you are trying to do, as you are most likely going about it the wrong way. According to the comment below, you say you need to use $sb from the url to run a query based on the id in $_SESSION['myarray']. Could you not just test using `$key=array_search($sb, $_SESSION['myarray']); if($key !== false){ echo "SB: ".$_SESSION['myarray'][$key]; }`

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a foreach directly inside of a switch statement

See the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

A switch should look like this:

```
switch($val){
 case 1:
  //some code... you can put a foreach here
  break;
 case 2:
  //you could do this if you want:
  foreach ($myArray as $key => $value){
    //do some stuff!
  }
  break;
 default:
  //some code for a default case
  break;
}
```

Also, `echo "id"$result;` is going to cause a problem for you. That should have the concatenate operator between it

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of what a case should look like, this is just the code for testing purposes. So is there any kind of loop I can put in a switch statement? I need to generate a case for each id in the $session.

Comment: If your cases are predictable and follow a pattern, a switch statement is probably not your best option. A simple foreach would probably do better. I only use cases when the code for each case is entirely different, then I typically will write a function that handles that case to keep my control structure clean.

Comment: The cases differ based on who is logged in. Lets say each user may have around 15 different digits between 1-500. The ?sb is used in the link to this page whereupon I need the id of the link that was clicked to carry out an SQL statement. Switch is the only way I can see this being possible - but if I can't generate the individual case for the possibilities then it isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` language construct is defined such that it can only consist of cases, and not arbitrary code blocks like your `for-each`.